# Best way to present incredibly detailed table?

Tags: usability, tables, usability-testing, info-visualisation, responsive-design

I'm trying to present a table on my site. The table is incredibly data heavy and can differ product to product.

The table needs to work in a responsive manner but still remain legible.

Can anybody recommend a best practice or examples of how they may have presented such data in the past? I've seen ZURB's responsive tables but I don't feel it's the best option...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Try switching format below a specific viewport size, and allow users to manage columns/data for what's most important to their context of use.

It seems like you have plenty of columns as is in the desktop view. For that view, you could use a First/last frozen column pattern, which is useful if you have actions that you need to perform per each row without needing to drill into a detail view:

#### For desktop and larger viewports: 1st and last frozen columns

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftvJVH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**Pro**

- Freeze column (or columns) depending on the must-see / do info
- Expands to larger viewports
- Managing columns allows users to tailor to their most important info

**Con**

- Scrolling as always is a trade off
- Users may forget which columns are hidden (maybe a visual indicator to show how many columns are available

#### For mobile and smaller views: stacking card tables

This [card stack: stackable.js](http://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js/) is one option I've used in the past, and hacked to display larger cards in a style I reformatted that worked for our requirements. Since a user can't see all the columns, it changes to a **label / value pair**. It's repetitive for a purpose.[image]

**Pro**

- Each card repeats the label, so value is always in context
- Cards can stretch to accomodate data which is highest priority
- You can add an 'Actions' icon persistent to mobile in the top right of each card (If that's your use case)

**Con**

- Cards, unlike a grid make it difficult to see values across multiple items for comparision (although you could still add sort controls above the cards)

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

- Do you really need to show all of that data at once? can you show the most important columns first and hide the rest under an option to "show all fields"?
- I would recommend right-aligning numbers
- Consider conditional formatting, like Excel offers- different colors in the background to visually communicate relative values, horizontal shaded bars for a "histogram" effect, or icons to highlight notable/interesting values